In rust, how to expose a method to external calls
I am using the windows_capture crate and trying the basic demo. However, the recording automatically stops. I want to manually control when the recording stops. How can I achieve this?
Can I only end recording in the in on_frame_arrived method? Is there any other way to stop external recording?
I tried adding the stop method to capture, but the effect was not very good. Maybe there was something wrong with my method.
this is demo
use std::{
    io::{self, Write},
    time::Instant,
};

use windows_capture::{
    capture::{Context, GraphicsCaptureApiHandler},
    encoder::{AudioSettingsBuilder, ContainerSettingsBuilder, VideoEncoder, VideoSettingsBuilder},
    frame::Frame,
    graphics_capture_api::InternalCaptureControl,
    monitor::Monitor,
    settings::{ColorFormat, CursorCaptureSettings, DrawBorderSettings, Settings},
};

// Handles capture events.
struct Capture {
    encoder: Option<VideoEncoder>,
    start: Instant,
}

impl GraphicsCaptureApiHandler for Capture {
    fn new(ctx: Context<Self::Flags>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        println!("Created with Flags: {}", ctx.flags);

        let encoder = VideoEncoder::new(
            VideoSettingsBuilder::new(1920, 1080),
            AudioSettingsBuilder::default().disabled(true),
            ContainerSettingsBuilder::default(),
            "video.mp4",
        )?;

        Ok(Self {
            encoder: Some(encoder),
            start: Instant::now(),
        })
    }

    // Called every time a new frame is available.
    fn on_frame_arrived(
        &mut self,
        frame: &mut Frame,
        capture_control: InternalCaptureControl,
    ) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        print!(
            "\rRecording for: {} seconds",
            self.start.elapsed().as_secs()
        );
        io::stdout().flush()?;

        // Stop the capture after 6 seconds
        if self.start.elapsed().as_secs() >= 6 {
            // Finish the encoder and save the video.
            self.encoder.take().unwrap().finish()?;

            capture_control.stop();

            // Because there wasn't any new lines in previous prints
            println!();
        }

        Ok(())
    }

    // Optional handler called when the capture item (usually a window) closes.
    fn on_closed(&mut self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        println!("Capture session ended");

        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Gets the foreground window, refer to the docs for other capture items
    let primary_monitor = Monitor::primary().expect("There is no primary monitor");

    let settings = Settings::new(
        // Item to capture
        primary_monitor,
        // Capture cursor settings
        CursorCaptureSettings::Default,
        // Draw border settings
        DrawBorderSettings::Default,
        // The desired color format for the captured frame.
        ColorFormat::Rgba8,
        // Additional flags for the capture settings that will be passed to user defined `new` function.
        "Yea this works".to_string(),
    );

    // Starts the capture and takes control of the current thread.
    // The errors from handler trait will end up here
    Capture::start(settings).expect("Screen capture failed");
}


You can use a flag in the struct, like stop: bool and check that in the function

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
